# I need to filter data id wise?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to filter data id wise for a part(vechile) but it fetches all results related to that instead of customer wise which is PID.My code is
Where i am going wrong?

```
    <?php 
   $sql="SELECT DISTINCT(PARTNO) FROM `paidamount` ORDER BY `PARTNO`";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($res);
if($num>0)
{
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

?>
<tr>
                  <td colspan="15" align="left" style="background-color:#006699;"><p style=" color:#FFFFFF;"><strong><?php echo $fetch['PARTNO']?></strong></p></td>
                      </tr>


        <?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM paidamount where paidamount.PARTNO='".$fetch['PARTNO']."' ORDER BY PARTNO";

//$sql="SELECT * FROM `paidamount`";
                    $result=mysql_query($sql);
                    $numrow=mysql_num_rows($result);

$i=1;
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{               
//echo $rows['id'];
 $imid=explode(",",$rows['issued_med']);
   $pmid=explode(",",$rows['ffffff']);

            ?>
```

Comment: I see no javascript nor ajax here

Comment: what is the name of the field you want to filter on? I dont see `PID` anywhere in your code?

Comment: thats what i am looking for where should i place it

Comment: @ZackNewsham any help pl

Comment: what is Your "paidamount" table structure? Provide table structure in Your question.

Comment: it will go in one of your two queries: as this `where PID='...'` in the first, or `and PID='...'` in the second. In both cases before the `ORDER ...`

Comment: table structure  id|Pid  |PARTNO |Payment |TotalPayment

Comment: @ZackNewsham ripa   can u come somewhere onlie so that i can show u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 $sql="SELECT DISTINCT(PARTNO) FROM `paidamount` ORDER BY `PARTNO`";
```

this query with below query:-

```
 $sql="SELECT DISTINCT(PARTNO) as PARTNO FROM `paidamount` ORDER BY `PARTNO`";
```

Comment: multi select drop down?